# What does this sort algorithm do?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

I am currently studying for an exam and in one of my professors older exams, he had this algorithm given, which should be analyzed...
It's an array field from 1 to 2n-1 and n is a power of two, in task a) n equals to 8 and the keys from 8-15 are given and we shall try out the algorithm and tell him, which m value is being returned.
Me personally have m=4, but I am not sure whether it is right or wrong and I would much rather get to know, what the algorithm does...
Unfortunately I just have a copy as an image and could not find the code in the internet...

[image: pseudocode for the algorithm]

Comment: You could have at least typed the algorithm properly on your computer... It hurts my eyes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP doesn't even show the least of effort to create a proper question

Comment: hey, sry for that, this is how I got it from a friend, I asked him to send me a better one, but he did not answer for a long time and since we are writing our exam tomorrow, I was in a hurry and thought someone with more experience and knowledge could immediately find out the name of the algorithm. it would be enough if someone could tell me the name... I could google it then

Answer (score 0):

I come to the conclusion that the while loop runs indefinitely because both `f(1)` and `f(2)` are equal to 2. So m is `f(3)` which is indeed 4.

In the first for loop the elements get accessed in groups of two and the smaller one gets assigned to the corresponding element at index `i` which isn't defined yet. After four iterations all former defined numbers are accessed and now 2 smaller numbers (from the execution before) are accessed. In addition `f` also gets the pair information.

Now the array should look like this `[2,2,4,3,2,5,4,  3,7,2,8,5,6,9,4]`  NOTE: the first element and `f(1)` is always the smallest number of the range `a[n...2n-1]` where `n` is a power of 2.

Than `m` gets defined as the bigger one of 2 or 4 (a[2] and a[3]) which is obviously 4. `k` is than f(1) which is the same as in the array: 2 (in the if `m` gets reassigned to 4)

So now there is the problem I mentioned earlier where `k = 2` and `f(k) = f(2) = 2 = k` where `k` is **never** bigger than `n - 1` which is required to break out of the while loop => No answer is the answer ;)